# How to add dropbox to file selection dialog box

Tags: menu, shortcuts, dropbox

I use dropbox very often and I have it installed in both windows and ubuntu.In windows,a shortcut to the dropbox folder is added automatically to the left panel of file/folder selection dialog box.
Now,how do I add this to ubuntu?I am running 15.04 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking the question; it made me realize I didn't have dropbox bookmarked on this system.

Open dropbax (the folder in Ubuntu).  In the top right corner you will see what I call the I/O gear.  Below that is another gear.  Hover over it and it will announce itself as "Location options."

Left-clicking on that gear will open a menu.  One of the items will be "Bookmark this location" about 2/3 of the way down.  The keybord shortcut is referenced Ctrl-D.

I should mention that I am using the Gnome desktop with Ubuntu 14.10.